# Word for the person who calls people on stage in a function

Tags: word-request

What is the person who welcomes the audience and calls people to stage in functions like graduation is called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use "master of ceremonies" or "emcee." The word "emcee" comes from the pronunciation of the abbreviation of master of ceremonies, "MC." Another less specific and casual option is "host."